# Test for one of multiple exceptions in Matlab unittests

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, exception

I am using Matlab's unittest to test the handling of invalid parameters.

In the test I have a line

```
t.verifyError(@myObject.myMethod, 'MATLAB:nonStrucReference');
```

which works fine in Matlab R2014a, but fails in Matlab R2016a with the message

```
---------------------
Framework Diagnostic:
---------------------
verifyError failed.
--> The function threw the wrong exception.

    Actual Exception:
        'MATLAB:structRefFromNonStruct'
    Expected Exception:
        'MATLAB:nonStrucReference'
```

I wonder if it would be possible to test whether one of the exceptions is thrown.

I know that it would be possible to write

```
t.verifyError(@myObject.myMethod, ?MException);
```

but something more specific would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would likely want to write a custom verification method which accepts a cell array of exceptions as the input.

```
function verifyOneOfErrors(testcase, func, identifiers, varargin)

    % Ensure that a cell array was passed rather than a string
    if ischar(identifiers)
        identifiers = {identifiers};
    end

    % If the function succeeds with no errors, then we want a failure
    threw_correct_error = false;

    try
        func()
    catch ME
        % Check if the identifier is in our list of approved identifiers
        threw_correct_error = ismember(ME.identifier, identifiers);
    end

    % Do the actual verification
    testcase.verifyTrue(threw_correct_error, varargin{:})
end
```

Another alternative is to actually get the error message identifier dynamically within your testcase by explicitly causing the error, and retrieving the identifier.

```
% Get a version-specific identifier for this specific error
try; a = []; a.field; catch ME; end;

% Verify that your method throws this error
t.verifyError(@myObject.myMethod, ME.identifier)
```